# How do I change the color on the lighting in different frames

Tags: animation, lighting, color, mixamo

Hi this is my first post on this website so sorry if there are any problems with this but let’s get into my question.

I have a scene where a character falls and I want a scene where there’s a light and then there are a bunch of colors flashing on the camera until it stops on one like a spin the wheel with colors but I don’t know how to change the colors in the frame so can anyone help?

Comment: Hello, you can create a keyframe (i) on the color of your light, then move the playhead in the timeline, change the color, keyframe again

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color by adding a keyframe in the frame where you want to start the color change and then going into the *World Properties* tab like this:
[image: press this to add a keyframe for world color change]

Then you can just go to the frame where you want the color change to end and press the keyframe button again as shown in the picture. then you click the color (in the picture I set it as a blue) and customize it to whatever color you want. You can do this a few times if you want it to flash through a bunch of different colors. If you put the start and ending keyframes right next to each other they will not fade and it will be an instant color switch.

Comment: You missed a part. 

If you want an instant switch in different times, _
select all keyframes, 
Right Click > Interpolation mode > Constant

Comment: yes but its easeir just to put the frames right next to each other so theres no real reason to change the fashion of it

Comment: What if they don't want it to be instant??

Comment: i already explained that at the beginning of the post

Comment: that would slowly change the color, not instantly change it when the keyframe comes

Comment: I know but if you want to put a fade then you can put them far away from each other and if you want it to be no transition you can just put the keyframes right next to each other and it would be pointless to go the extra step

Comment: If you want it to be no transition + change every 0.5 second rather than immediate?